# Why is the skin of European bog bodies brown?

Tags: human-biology, skin, anthropology, decomposition

What causes this? Is it to do with decay or is it to do with substances within the bog dying the skin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The anaerobic decomposition of moss produces tannins in the peat.

> The bog water interacts with the acids in the moss and produce tannin
>   and other chemicals that preserve the bodies that fall or are cast
>   into the bog; hence the numerous well-preserved bog bodies.
>   http://www.digitalmedievalist.com/opinionated-celtic-faqs/bog-bodies/

The tannins tan the bodies just like tanning leather; the color of the bodies darken and the tanning action also preserves them.